# Array of objects, filter out values with 0

Tags: javascript, filter

I would like to remove the `key + value` of objects which have value of 0. the timestamp should stay in place.

```js
var array = [{
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T00:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 78.09482851766388
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T01:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 124.09589189108233
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T02:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 106.97921714748477
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T03:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 118.7469310337081
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T04:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 119.81672320518294
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T05:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 67.39690680291541
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T06:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 117.67713886223325
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T07:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 87.72295806093751
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T08:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 115.53755451928356
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T09:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 78.09482851766388
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T10:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 48.14064771636815
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T11:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 67.39690680291541
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T12:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 130.5146449199314
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T13:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 128.37506057698172
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T14:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 73.81565983176449
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T15:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 109.11880149043446
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T16:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 127.30526840550688
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T17:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 123.02609971960749
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T18:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T19:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T20:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T21:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T22:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T23:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-19T00:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-19T01:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-19T02:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-19T03:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-19T04:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-19T05:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-19T06:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-19T07:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-19T08:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-19T09:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-19T10:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-19T11:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}]


var abc = array.filter((object) => {
  let keys = []
  for (let key in object) {
    if (key !== 'timestamp') keys.push(key)
  }
  return keys.map(key => object[key] > 0)
})

console.log(abc)
```

However my code doesn't remove 0 values

Comment: I don't see any code in here that attempts to filter out zeros. Doesn't Javascript have a `filter` function?

Comment: Are you saying you want to remove any properties that have a 0 value? Or that you want to get all timestamps associated with non-zero values?

Comment: the keys of the objects are unkown. I did filter out all objects, stored the keys which are not `timestamp` and returned only `> 0`

Comment: the timestamp + the [key] [value] of keys which are greater then 0

Comment: @JasonBrill `map` doesn't filter. You're just creating a list of boolean values with that map by the looks of it. I think you meant `filter`.

Comment: `var abc = array.filter((object) => {`

Comment: @JasonBrill Again, are you saying to want to return everything *but* keys with a value of 0? If not, I don't understand what you're asking. Also, `map` is always going to return an array equal in length to the original array. No filtering is taking places.

Comment: I dont want to filter out, I want to return the same array length, with the keys deleted. they ones which are 0

Comment: the result would be `[{ timestamp: y }, { Test Bar 0: x, timestamp: y }] etc..`

Answer (score 1):

You could just delete the property with the value `0`.

```js
var array = [{ timestamp: "2017-01-18T00:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 78.09482851766388 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-18T01:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 124.09589189108233 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-18T02:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 106.97921714748477 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-18T03:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 118.7469310337081 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-18T04:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 119.81672320518294 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-18T05:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 67.39690680291541 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-18T06:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 117.67713886223325 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-18T07:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 87.72295806093751 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-18T08:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 115.53755451928356 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-18T09:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 78.09482851766388 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-18T10:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 48.14064771636815 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-18T11:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 67.39690680291541 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-18T12:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 130.5146449199314 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-18T13:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 128.37506057698172 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-18T14:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 73.81565983176449 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-18T15:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 109.11880149043446 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-18T16:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 127.30526840550688 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-18T17:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 123.02609971960748 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-18T18:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 0 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-18T19:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 0 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-18T20:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 0 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-18T21:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 0 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-18T22:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 0 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-18T23:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 0 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-19T00:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 0 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-19T01:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 0 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-19T02:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 0 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-19T03:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 0 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-19T04:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 0 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-19T05:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 0 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-19T06:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 0 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-19T07:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 0 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-19T08:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 0 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-19T09:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 0 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-19T10:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 0 }, { timestamp: "2017-01-19T11:00:00.000Z", "Test Bar 0": 0 }];

array.forEach(o => Object.keys(o).forEach(k => {
    if (k !== 'timestamp' && o[k] === 0) {
        delete o[k];
    }
}));

console.log(array);
```

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your keys.map is wrong:

```
var abc = array.forEach((object) => {
  for(key in object){
    if(key!=="timestamp"&&(object[key]==0||object[key]=="0") {
        delete object[key];
     }
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a simple `filter` statement

```js
var array = [{"timestamp":"2017-01-18T00:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":78.09482851766388},{"timestamp":"2017-01-18T01:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":124.09589189108233},{"timestamp":"2017-01-18T02:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":106.97921714748477},{"timestamp":"2017-01-18T03:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":118.7469310337081},{"timestamp":"2017-01-18T04:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":119.81672320518294},{"timestamp":"2017-01-18T05:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":67.39690680291541},{"timestamp":"2017-01-18T06:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":117.67713886223325},{"timestamp":"2017-01-18T07:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":87.72295806093751},{"timestamp":"2017-01-18T08:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":115.53755451928356},{"timestamp":"2017-01-18T09:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":78.09482851766388},{"timestamp":"2017-01-18T10:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":48.14064771636815},{"timestamp":"2017-01-18T11:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":67.39690680291541},{"timestamp":"2017-01-18T12:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":130.5146449199314},{"timestamp":"2017-01-18T13:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":128.37506057698172},{"timestamp":"2017-01-18T14:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":73.81565983176449},{"timestamp":"2017-01-18T15:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":109.11880149043446},{"timestamp":"2017-01-18T16:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":127.30526840550688},{"timestamp":"2017-01-18T17:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":123.02609971960749},{"timestamp":"2017-01-18T18:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":0},{"timestamp":"2017-01-18T19:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":0},{"timestamp":"2017-01-18T20:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":0},{"timestamp":"2017-01-18T21:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":0},{"timestamp":"2017-01-18T22:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":0},{"timestamp":"2017-01-18T23:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":0},{"timestamp":"2017-01-19T00:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":0},{"timestamp":"2017-01-19T01:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":0},{"timestamp":"2017-01-19T02:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":0},{"timestamp":"2017-01-19T03:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":0},{"timestamp":"2017-01-19T04:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":0},{"timestamp":"2017-01-19T05:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":0},{"timestamp":"2017-01-19T06:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":0},{"timestamp":"2017-01-19T07:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":0},{"timestamp":"2017-01-19T08:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":0},{"timestamp":"2017-01-19T09:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":0},{"timestamp":"2017-01-19T10:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":0},{"timestamp":"2017-01-19T11:00:00.000Z","Test Bar 0":0}];

console.log(array.filter(o => o["Test Bar 0"] > 0));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all keys which have a value of `0` you don't need to filter at all. Just iterate through the list and delete any properties with a value of `0`.

```js
var array = [{
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T00:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 78.09482851766388
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T01:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 124.09589189108233
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T02:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 106.97921714748477
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T03:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 118.7469310337081
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T04:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 119.81672320518294
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T05:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 67.39690680291541
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T06:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 117.67713886223325
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T07:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 87.72295806093751
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T08:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 115.53755451928356
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T09:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 78.09482851766388
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T10:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 48.14064771636815
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T11:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 67.39690680291541
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T12:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 130.5146449199314
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T13:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 128.37506057698172
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T14:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 73.81565983176449
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T15:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 109.11880149043446
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T16:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 127.30526840550688
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T17:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 123.02609971960749
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T18:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T19:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T20:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T21:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T22:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-18T23:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-19T00:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-19T01:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-19T02:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-19T03:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-19T04:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-19T05:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-19T06:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-19T07:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-19T08:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-19T09:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-19T10:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}, {
  "timestamp": "2017-01-19T11:00:00.000Z",
  "Test Bar 0": 0
}];

array.forEach((object) => {
  Object.keys(object).forEach((key) => {
    if (object[key] === 0) {
      delete object[key];
    }
  });
});

console.log(array);
```